# IF column has a duplicated value THEN choose the next one

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, legacy

Thanks for looking into this.

How do I write an IF statement in Bigquery SQL, to sum up, the numbers of units (If the QUARTER columns have the SAME quarter then choose the unit number with TYPE ACTL, OTLK, ETC). TYPE CWV are historical data so it's ok to have duplicated quarters but if there are units with TYPE ACTL, OTLK, etc with the same quarter as in CWV then I would like the SQL to choose UNITS with TYPE ACTL, OTLK, etc over CWV.

Note: this sql will be used for Tableau and my total of units for XYZ should be 977071 (excluding the CWV / FY20-Q4 / 104955)

| Row | TMC_BC | TYPE | PROGRAM | QUARTER | UNITS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | TMC | ACTL | XYZ | FY20-Q2 | 0 |
| 2 | TMC | OTLK | XYZ | FY20-Q3 | 6500 |
| ***3*** | ***TMC*** | ***CWV*** | ***XYZ*** | ***FY20-Q4*** | ***104955*** |
| **4** | **TMC** | **ACTL** | **XYZ** | **FY20-Q4** | **191300** |
| 5 | TMC | CWV | XYZ | FY21-Q1 | 182448 |
| 6 | TMC_BC | CWV | XYZ | FY21-Q2 | 91346 |
| 7 | TMC | CWV | XYZ | FY21-Q2 | 158126 |
| 8 | TMC_BC | CWV | XYZ | FY21-Q1 | 62500 |
| 9 | TMC | CWV | XYZ | FY21-Q1 | 157287 |
| 10 | TMC_BC | CWV | XYZ | FY21-Q1 | 62500 |
| 11 | TMC | CWV | XYZ | FY21-Q1 | 31410 |
| 12 | TMC_BC | CWV | XYZ | FY21-Q1 | 33654 |

my current SQL:

```
SELECT
case when tmc <= 0 then 'TMC_BC'
      else 'TMC'
      end as TMC_BC,
TYPE,
PROGRAM,
QUARTER,
sum(ca) as UNITS,
from xx_REPORTS
where PROGRAM like 'XYZ'
and TYPE <> 'PDP' and TYPE <> 'POR'
and GEO = 'NA'
group by 1,2,3,4
order by 4 asc
```

Comment: Edit your question and be clear about the results you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm . . . If I understand correctly, you want `'CWV'` only when there are no other types for the quarter/PROGRAM/tmc_bc combination.  You can use window functions for this filtering:

```
select r.*
from (select r.*,
             count(*) over (partition by quarter, program, tmc_bc) as q_cnt,
             countif(type = 'CWV') over (partition by quarter, program, tmc_bc) as q_cnt_cwv
      from xx_REPORTS r
     ) r
where (q_cnt = q_cnt_cwv) or (type <> 'CWV');
```

Actually, if the logic is correct, then what you want are non-CMV rows if there are any, otherwise all rows.  A simpler expression is:

```
select r.*
from (select r.*,
             countif(type <> 'CWV') over (partition by quarter, program, tmc_bc) as q_cnt_noncwv
      from xx_REPORTS r
     ) r
where (q_cnt_noncwv > 0 and type <> 'CWV') or q.cnt_noncwv = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks but how do I write this with my current script, I'm still new to this.

```select r.*
from (select r.*,
             countif(type <> 'CWV') over (partition by quarter, program, tmc_bc) as q_cnt_noncwv
      from xx_REPORTS r
     ) r
where (q_cnt_noncwv > 0 and type <> 'CWV') or q.cnt_noncwv = 0;```

Comment: @QuicKick . . . Put the `countif()` in a subquery and add the `where` condition to the outer query.  You can filter in the subquery as well, if that is important for determining duplicates.

Comment: ```SELECT
case when tmc <= 0 then 'TMC_BC'
      else 'TMC'<br/>
      end as TMC_BC,
TYPE,
PROGRAM,
QUARTER,
sum(ca) as UNITS
countif(bc.type <> 'CWV') over (partition by quarter, program, TMC_BC) as q_cnt_noncwv,
FROM xx_REPORTS bc
where PROGRAM like "XYZ"
and TYPE <> "PDP" and TYPE <> "POR"
and GEO = "NA"
group by 1,2,3,4
where q_cnt_noncwv > 0 and bc.type <> 'CWV' or q.cnt_noncwv = 0
order by 4 asc
```